# How can you move materials between scenekit scenes in the User Interface? (or share materials)

Tags: scenekit, material-swift

I have one geometry that has a material I really like. I want to bring in many more geometries and start with the same settings, because it takes along time to balance all the settings and get a nice effect. I've been trying to match the settings or find a way to get give the new geometry the same material without any luck. (Yes, this could be done in code, but I'd rather it be possible to see the effects in the UI as well.) Is there anyway to move a material from one scene to another in the UI, and then apply it to a new geometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the utilities panel on the right, show the material inspector. At the very top the materials applied to your currently selected geometry is displayed. If you click the `+` button, all the materials in your scene will be shown and you can assign them from there.

Select the new geometry and assign the material you like.

I just started using XCode so there is probably a better way of doing this.

Comment: This worked for me. (thx) For others viewing this, my Utilities panel was on the right.

Comment: don't know my left from right apparently. mine is on the right too - i corrected my answer